# Unable to build ipa for IOS 4.3 on phonegap 2.4

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am making a hybrid app using using HTML5 , javascript , jQuery and Phone gap 2.4 .The app **works fine with iOS 6 in iPhone 5** but I am **unable to build an ipa for IOS 4.3 for iPhone 4S**. I have changed the deployment target to 4.3 but still it doesn't work . Can anyone please guide me the steps to change the settings for building the ipa for IOS 4.3. I am new to Phonegap 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap stopped support for iOS4.x with the release of PhoneGap 2.4.0 . check the release notes: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/whats-new-in-cordova-ios-2-4-0/

If you need to support iOs4.x, please use a previous version of PhoneGap.

Comment: thanx. I did checked the same .